# Changing language option on ColorNote

Tags: languages, colornote

By accident, on the Android ColorNote application, I changed the language from English to Chinese. How do I change it back to English?

Comment: It's probably easiest to clear the application data and cache for Colornote. What device are you using and what version of Android?

Comment: Perhaps you already don't have this issue anymore, but could you provide the link to this app, so that this question can be answerable? I searched "ColorNote" on Play Store and I found [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.socialnmobile.dictapps.notepad.color.note). Is it the app you're using? However, I don't find any settings to change the language. Instead, it follows the device's language.